# Tycho projects without Java code have Java nature in Eclipse

Tags: eclipse, maven, m2eclipse, tycho

I have imported my Tycho project in Eclipse using m2eclipse and I have the following issue: Tycho adds the Java nature to `eclipse-plugin` projects that don't have any Java code, for example the help plugin. It's not a big deal, but I find it annoying.

Is there any way to disable this?

Comment: Tycho certainly doesn't do this - the Tycho configuration is independent of the Eclipse project nature and other configuration. So you are apparently also using something else than Tycho (m2eclipse?) but that information is missing in your question.

Comment: I might have conflated m2eclipse and tycho in my mind, but this happens for projects packaged as eclipse-plugin and if I'm not mistaken this packaging type is contributed by tycho and m2e should not know anything specific abou it. On the other hand, I think it only happens in Eclipse, not from CLI, and this points to m2e. I will investigate further,. Thanks!

Comment: m2e has an extension concept so that it can handle Tycho projects without having to know about Tycho itself: Shen importing a project, it checks a registry and automatically installs the "Tycho Project Configurators" for Tycho projects. This configurator probably sets the Java nature.

Comment: Isn't the tycho configurator a part of tycho?

Comment: The tool "Tycho" is only the Maven extension. The "Tycho project configurator" is another tool from the Tycho ecosystem.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Tycho doesn't define a separate packaging type for Eclipse plug-ins without code.

So if the Tycho Project Configurator, i.e. the m2eclipse extension for Tycho, wanted to omit the Java nature for `eclipse-plugin` projects, it could only do so after scanning the entire project for `*.java` files. And even then it would not be clear if the project does *not* contain Java code, or simply *not yet* contain Java code.

So, having the Java nature on all `eclipse-plugin` projects is a simple and robust choice that makes sense IMHO.

Comment: I see, thank you for providing the details behind this choice.